# SwiftUI animated transition problem with binding values

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, binding

I surely have a problem understanding SwiftUI transition animations. I have reduced my problem to a very simple example.

It seems that when animating transition, if you use a `Binding` the state changes immediately and then the transition occurs between the view with the new state, and itself. Whereas using no `Binding` the transition occurs properly between the old state view, and the new state view.

To summarize :

| With Binding (problematic) | Without Binding (works as expected) |
| --- | --- |
| 1. Old State | 1. Old State |
| 2. Tap | 2. Tap |
| 3. **New State** ⚠️ | 3. Old State |
| 4. Animation | 4. Animation |
| 5. New State | 5. New State |

Here's an example:

[image: The animated problem]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var state: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            LetterView(state: $state)
                .id(state)
                .transition(.scale.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 3)))
            
            Button("Toggle") {
                withAnimation {
                    self.state.toggle()
                }
            }
            
            Text(state ? "A" : "B")
                .bold()
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .id(state)
                .transition(.scale.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 3)))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct LetterView: View {
    @Binding var state: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Text(state ? "A" : "B")
            .bold()
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

So, may anyone tell me why it works like this, and what am I doing wrong. But most importantly, how can I fix the transition while keeping my `Binding`?

**Note:** I know the `Binding` in the example is useless, but it's for the sake of the simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure why, but moving the `.id`into the subview fixes it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var state: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            LetterView(state: $state)
//                .id(state)
                .transition(.scale.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 3)))
            
            Button("Toggle") {
                    self.state.toggle()
            }
            
            Text(state ? "A" : "B")
                .bold()
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .id(state)
                .transition(.scale.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 3)))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct LetterView: View {
    @Binding var state: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Text(state ? "A" : "B")
            .bold()
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .id(state) // here
    }
}
```

I suppose its a matter of when which view id gets refreshed, and it seems that the id change has to happen on the text with the ternary operator itself.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. I'm still puzzled, though, by this behavior as I have never found any documentation mentioning it.